# How to get a document and edit data without calling db.collection again?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the value of a field and then update if it satisfy a condition. I would like to understand which is the best way. For example I set this document (taken from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document)):

```
db.collection('cities')
  .doc('LA')
  .set({
    name: 'Los Angeles',
    state: 'CA',
    country: 'USA',
    numberOfRestaurant: 100
   });
```

I want to decrease by 1 the value of `numberOfRestaurant`. Suppose this is inside a function.

```
db.collection('cities')
  .doc('LA')
  .get()
  .then(function(doc) {
    var numberOfRestaurant = doc.get('numberOfRestaurant');
    if (numberOfRestaurant > 0)
      db.collection('cities')
        .doc('LA')
        .update({ numberOfRestaurant: numberOfRestaurant - 1 });
    else 
      alert("Can't set negative number");
   });
```

This way I'm calling db.collection 2 times. Is it possible to use the `querySnapshot` object to update the value without calling db.collection again. Something like this (I know this way gives an error):

```
db.collection('cities')
  .doc('LA')
  .get()
  .then(function(doc) {
    var numberOfRestaurant = doc.get('numberOfRestaurant');
      if (numberOfRestaurant > 0) 
         doc.update({ numberOfRestaurant: numberOfRestaurant - 1 });
      else 
        alert("Can't set negative number");
   });
```

From the [Api Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) `.get()` return a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. I must use .ref that returns a `DocumentReference` which refers to a document location in a Firestore database.

```
db.collection('cities')
  .doc('LA')
  .get()
  .then(function(doc) {
    var numberOfRestaurant = doc.get('numberOfRestaurant');
      if (numberOfRestaurant > 0) 
         doc.ref.update({ numberOfRestaurant: numberOfRestaurant - 1 });
      else 
        alert("Can't set negative number");
   });
```